# multi sub on Array of Int vs Array of Array of Int

Tags: raku

I'd like to have a multi sub where one is for an array of Ints and the other multi sub is for an array of array of Ints.

This seems to do the trick:

```
multi sub abc(Int @array) { say 10; }

multi sub abc(Array[Int] @array) { say 20; }
```

But, building literals that satisfy those constraints is quite verbose:

```
abc Array[Int].new([1,2,3]);   # -> 10

abc Array[Array[Int]].new([Array[Int].new([1,2,3]), Array[Int].new([2,3,4])]);   # -> 20
```

Ideally, I'd be able to just say:

```
abc [1,2,3]
abc [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]
```

Is there a way to build an `abc` which can dispatch as shown above without all the explicit type annotations?

Can a `multi sub` be setup to dispatch at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a cheap nominal type check, you can perform an expensive structural check with a `where` clause, eg

```
multi sub abc(@array-of-Int where .all ~~ Int) { ... }
```

or

```
multi sub abc(@matrix-of-Int where .all ~~ Positional & { .all ~~ Int }) { ... }
```

If you go the route of nominal types, shaped arrays might also be worth considering, which can be declared even more compactly via anonymous variables

```
abc my Int @[2;3] = (1,2,3), (2,3,4);
abc Array[Int].new(:shape(2,3), (1,2,3), (2,3,4));
```

and checked via

```
multi sub abc(Array[Int] $matrix where .shape == 2) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks Christoph!