# Typed array from non-typed array

Tags: raku

Let's say we have the following `multi sub`:

```
multi sub abc(Int        @array) { say 10, ' ', @array; }

multi sub abc(Array[Int] @array) { say 20, ' ', @array; }

multi sub abc(Str        @array) { say 30, ' ', @array; }

multi sub abc(Array[Str] @array) { say 40, ' ', @array; }
```

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45344618/multi-sub-on-array-of-int-vs-array-of-array-of-int), calling these with typed arrays can get verbose:

```
abc Array[Int].new([1,2,3]);

abc Array[Array[Int]].new([Array[Int].new([1,2,3]), Array[Int].new([2,3,4])]);
```

It would be nice if the type could be inferred from the literal such that we could do something like this:

```
abc typed([1,2,3]);

abc typed([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]);

abc typed(['a', 'b', 'c']);

abc typed([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'd']]);
```

Going further, let's add a clause which does the type inference for us:

```
multi sub abc(@array) { abc typed(@array); }
```

Now we can get the full inference with no extra imposed syntax:

```
abc [1,2,3];

abc [[1,2,3],[2,3,4]];

abc ['a', 'b', 'c'];

abc [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'd']];
```

The above displays the following:

```
10 [1 2 3]
20 [[1 2 3] [2 3 4]]
30 [a b c]
40 [[a b c] [b c d]]
```

Below is a simple version of `typed` which works on:

- `Array[Int]`
- `Array[Array[Int]]`
- `Array[Str]`
- `Array[Array[Str]]`

My question is, how would you go about implementing this sort of type inference? Is there a better approach? Is there already a similar facility available?

```
sub type-of(\obj)
{
    if obj.^name eq 'Array'
    {
        if obj.map({ type-of($_).^name }).all eq obj.map({ type-of($_).^name })[0]
        {
            my $type = type-of(obj[0]);
            return Array[$type];
        }
        return Array;
    }

    if obj.^name eq 'Int' { return Int; }
    if obj.^name eq 'Str' { return Str; }
}

sub typed(\obj)
{
    if obj.^name eq 'Array'
    {
        return type-of(obj)(obj.List.map({ $_.&typed }).Array);
    }

    return (type-of(obj))(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> calling these with typed arrays can get verbose

Perhaps you're overdoing it a bit with type-constraints on everything?

You can also store the type in a constant, shortening your code a bit:

```
my constant AI = Array[Int];
dd AI.new([1,2,3]);
dd Array[AI].new([AI.new([1,2,3]), AI.new([2,3,4])]);
```

> My question is, how would you go about implementing this sort of type inference?

The [`.WHAT` pseudo-method](https://docs.perl6.org/language/mop#index-entry-syntax_WHAT-WHAT) returns the type object of the invocant. So you can use that to get the type of the thing and you can use [`=:=` container identity operator](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/=:=) to figure out if you're dealing with an `Array`. (Alternatively, you could use [`~~` smartmatch](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/~~) instead, and that way catch subclasses of `Array` as well).

Here's a sample implementation of such use, using a custom circumfix operator:

```
sub circumfix:<♥[ ]> (|c) {
    my \array = circumfix:<[ ]>(|c);
    return array unless try array.elems;

    (my $type := array.head.WHAT) =:= Array
      and $type := (array[0] = circumfix:<♥[ ]>(array.head<>)).WHAT;

    my $type-it := True;
    for array.tail: *-1 {
        (my $el-type := .WHAT) =:= Array
          and $el-type := ($_ = circumfix:<♥[ ]>(.<>)).WHAT;
        next if $el-type =:= $type;
        $type-it := False;
    }
    $type-it ?? Array[$type].new: array !! array
}

dd ♥[<1 2 3>];
dd ♥[<a b c>];
dd ♥[[1e0,2], [2,3], [3,3]];
dd ♥[[1,2], [2,3], [3,3]];
dd ♥[[[[1],],],];

# OUTPUT:
# Array[IntStr].new(IntStr.new(1, "1"), IntStr.new(2, "2"), IntStr.new(3, "3"))
# Array[Str].new("a", "b", "c")
# [[1e0, 2], Array[Int].new(2, 3), Array[Int].new(3, 3)]
# Array[Array[Int]].new(Array[Int].new(1, 2), Array[Int].new(2, 3), Array[Int].new(3, 3))
# Array[Array[Array[Array[Int]]]].new(Array[Array[Array[Int]]].new(Array[Array[Int]].new(Array[Int].new(1))))
```

We use a [`|c` to capture the args](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature#Capture_Parameters) and simply give them to core `[ ]` circumfix that will make a regular `Array` for us.

Then, we [`try`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/exceptions#index-entry-try-try) to see if the `Array` we got has any elements: if it doesn't, we won't know how to parametarize it and lazy things won't let us find out the `.elems`, hence the `try`.

At this point, we know we have at least one element in our `Array`, so we grab it and use `.WHAT` to get its type. Then, we use `=:=` to check if it's an `Array`, and if it is, we simply recurse on it, store the result, update the `$type` to the returned type. The `<>` bit is just to [decont the `Array`](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2017/12/02/#theoneandonly):

```
    (my $type := array.head.WHAT) =:= Array
      and $type := (array[0] = circumfix:<♥[ ]>(array.head<>)).WHAT;
```

Next, we have the `for` loop. We start with the second element, since we already took care of the first one when we were figuring out what type to use.

If any other elements are not of the same type as `$type` we can't parametarize our `Array`, so we simply loop and check their types, doing the same business with recursing on `Arrays`. If we spot any differing type we set a flag (`$type-it`), to indicate that current `Array` should not be parametarized (we still keep looping, so that we recurse and parametarize any remaining `Array`s).

At the end, if the flag is set, we use the `$type` to parametarize a new `Array` with; otherwise we return our `array` as is.

Simples :)

---

P.S.: it's worth noting Perl 6 supports self-referential `Arrays`, and the above code would hang with, say, this setup:

```
my @a; @a[0] = @a;
dd ♥[@a];
```

You'd need to implement something that marks things it has seen already; [something similar to this](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/beaad7b97/src/core/Mu.pm#L583-L605) (if you convert NQP code to pure Perl 6)